# How do I set up a library for textures?

Tags: texturing, blend-files

(TLDR already? Scroll down.)
How do I set up a library of textures? I introduced blender at my workplace (architect) and this *oldschool* office still works with sketchup instead of 3d designing with revit, allplan, or what have you. Well since I'm new and I need to render some of those projects I have a problem: sketchup models only have their textures when being in blender render mode. When I switch to cycles they get replaced with a flat color (at least matching the texture they had before). We have a lot of projects in the going and they change regularly. But we need constant visual updates in form of rendering etc.

TLDR:
I want to edit the textures of every given project ONCE even when a more up-to-date-sketchup model comes my way. So how do I set up a library of different textures that I can chose from in every project? I read about appending but this is not the best way. If that's possible I want it to be like a catalog of textures (with the preview spheres) where I can just chose from, not a shitload of project files which I all have to open and search for the right thing in.

Comment: did you check out the cycles material nodes and made sure your Image Texture is connected like it should?

Comment: Did you try UV unwrapping your mesh? I doubt that would be the problem, but it's worth a shot.